# How to add fading effect to this javascript code

Tags: javascript, fade

```
 <div id="changeText" ></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var text = ["Welcome", "Hi", "Sup dude"];
var counter = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
setInterval(change, 1000);
function change() {
 elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
    counter++;
    if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0; }
}
</script>
```

how do i add fading effect to this javascript code? also, how do i make it start with "welcome" instead of a blank? I'd be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you dont want to add jQuery

```
    var text = ["Welcome", "Hi", "Sup dude"];
var counter = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
elem.style.opacity = 0;
var opCounter = 0;
setInterval(change, 3000);
function change() {
 elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
    setInterval(opChange, 300);
    counter++;
    if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0; }
    elem.style.opacity = 0;
    opCounter = 0;
}
function opChange(){
        elem.style.opacity = opCounter;
    opCounter = opCounter + 0.1;
}
```

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6yd5x/)

Comment: you can add that as well by overwriting opChange function. small logic required to reduce opacity after it reaches at opacity level 1